# What prevents someone from uploading thousands of files to Amazon S3, after they have the signed policy document?

Tags: forms, security, upload, amazon-s3

I feel that I must be missing something here, because it seems to me that once someone has your [signed policy document](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1), is there anything preventing them from just going ahead and uploading thousands of documents to your S3 bucket? Am I missing something here? Is there something that makes the signature valid for only one upload?

Answer (score 1):

The policy document contains an expiration field that you set to limit the life of the policy.

From the Amazon site:

expiration - A Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) timestamp that specifies when the policy document will expire. Once a policy document has expired, the upload form will no longer work.

```
{"expiration": "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "conditions": [ 
    {"bucket": "s3-bucket"}, 
    ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
    {"acl": "private"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
   ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
 ]
}
```

I thought I had read somewhere that the max length for a bucket to live is 36 hours, but I could not find that when I looked just now.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing within S3 to limit the number of files that someone with your policy doc can upload.

If this is a concern then I would suggest that you wrap the S3 upload with something else that will perform the check on the number of files one of your clients is allowed to upload.